# Error in reading hdf file

Tags: java, hdf5, visad

I tried to download libhdfeos.dll file but I am not getting the file on net.
I found libhdfeos.so but that is for Ubuntu and not for Windows.

I find this error when I am trying to open this file.

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no hdfeos in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1878)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
        at visad.data.hdfeos.hdfeosc.HdfeosLib.<clinit>(HdfeosLib.java:29)
        at visad.data.hdfeos.HdfeosFile.<init>(HdfeosFile.java:49)
        at visad.data.hdfeos.HdfeosForm.open(HdfeosForm.java:56)
        at myapp.hfAdapter.<init>(hfAdapter.java:41)
        at myapp.hfAdapter.main(hfAdapter.java:91)
```

Comment: Java applications require JAR files and not DLL's.

Comment: @npinti--Some jar files require native codes and which needs dll.